# SuperCollider without OSC

Tags: supercollider, opensoundcontrol

I have used PD in the past, but right now I'd like to try using SuperCollider for this one project. Specifically, I'd like to research control protocol and try swapping OSC for CoAP.

I'm trying to figure how deeply `scsynth` depends on OSC? Is there is a simple object interface I'd need to implement or it's all over the code? I tried some greping, but got a bit confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scsynth` depends extremely heavily on OSC - I'd imagine there's basically no way to use it without OSC. It's baked in to the system design, it's not just an external add-on to control it.

Note that you don't need to use OSC over TCP/UDP, but that's the standard setup. When we ported `scsynth` to Android, for example, we controlled it by sending OSC commands via Android's "intents". If you implemented a CoAP wrapper, I'd imagine you would end up invoking OSC commands in-memory.

Here is the [SuperCollider server OSC command reference](http://doc.sccode.org/Reference/Server-Command-Reference.html) which shows the entire list of commands the server knows. Also the [SC guide to OSC communication](http://doc.sccode.org/Guides/OSC_communication.html).